# Why layout-large-v11 resource does not apply on Android 4.0 WVGA800 phone

Tags: android, compatibility

I am testing with Google's iosched2011 app, and tested with a 4.0.3 simulator.

I am wondering why layout-large-v11 resource does not apply on Android 4.0 WVGA800 phone. It looks like 800*480 is taken as a large screen, and android 4.0's API level is big than 11. So it should apply the resource on that folder in this phone, but it turns out not.

Comment: I don't see the option to specify the api level listed at http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html any link?

Comment: Here's the doc about providing different versions of resources, and the resolution rules: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#AlternativeResources

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check in your app how Android sets configuration:

in activity onCreate add this:

```
Configuration cfg = getApplication().getResources().getConfiguration();
int sz = cfg.screenLayout&cfg.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_MASK;
System.out.println("size: "+sz);
```

in logcat you'll see number, one of [these](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Configuration.html#SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_LARGE).

On Samsung Galaxy Nexus with 4,65' screen I get 2 = SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_NORMAL. So you can expect same.

From Docs:

> A set of four generalized sizes: small, normal, large, and xlarge
>
> Note: Beginning with Android 3.2 (API level 13), these size groups are
>   deprecated in favor of a new technique for managing screen sizes based
>   on the available screen width. If you're developing for Android 3.2
>   and greater, see [Declaring Tablet Layouts for Android 3.2](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#DeclaringTabletLayouts) for more
>   information.

Answer (score 0):

What [mice](https://stackoverflow.com/users/907695/mice) said.  Your screen size category should always be primarily a function of its physical dimension, not the pixel count.

Furthermore, and logically, all screens of the same size class should be round about the same size in dp (density-independent pixels).

For more details, see: http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#range

So no, your phone should not be LARGE, no matter how many pixels it has.  If it's big enough to be large, then you'll look quite silly holding it up to your head.